# Need to update a table with an iterative number based on a subquery

Tags: mysql, join, update

Massive edit to follow procedure and enable reproducing this in a fiddler somewhere.

Table 1, `schedule`:

```
CREATE TABLE `schedule` (
  `scheduleid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `sessionid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `roomid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `starttime` time NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00',
  `schorder` int(11) DEFAULT NUL
);
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO `schedule` (scheduleid, sessionid, roomid, starttime) VALUES (1, 13, 2, '18:00');
INSERT INTO `schedule` (scheduleid, sessionid, roomid, starttime) VALUES (2, 17, 3, '19:00');
INSERT INTO `schedule` (scheduleid, sessionid, roomid, starttime) VALUES (3, 18, 2, '19:00');
INSERT INTO `schedule` (scheduleid, sessionid, roomid, starttime) VALUES (4, 23, 2, '17:00');
```

Table 2, `rooms`:

```
CREATE TABLE `rooms` (
  `roomid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `sort_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
);
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO `rooms` (roomid, sort_order) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO `rooms` (roomid, sort_order) VALUES (3, 2);
```

The `SELECT` statement that gets me the schedule in order by start time, then room sort order:

```
SELECT
    SCH.starttime,
    R.roomid,
    SCH.sessionid
    FROM
         schedule SCH
    JOIN rooms R USING (roomid)
    ORDER BY
        SCH.starttime, R.sort_order;
```

The result of that `SELECT` statement, which is accurate:

```
┌─────────────┬────────┬───────────┐
│SCH.starttime│R.roomid│S.sessionid│
├─────────────┼────────┼───────────┤
│17:00        │2       │23         │
│18:00        │2       │13         │
│19:00        │2       │18         │
│19:00        │3       │17         │
└─────────────┴────────┴───────────┘
```

What I want to do is use that result to update the `sch_order` field in the `schedule` table with an incrementing number.

Is that possible? If so, how would I do it?

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ba411/1/0) for the above.

[ETA] Complicating factor: I'm on a hosted server, and I don't have temporary table privileges.

Comment: Can you please give us your table structures as DDL ('CREATE TABLE blah (...);`) and your table data in the form of DML (`INSERT INTO blah VALUES (...);`). Help us to help you. There are a few articles on how to ask questions here on my profile - you might want to take a look? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Sure thing! Thanks for the pointer; I'll go edit it now.

Comment: Show us the `SELECT` that will deliver the rows in the desired order, then we can tell you how to tack on an "incrementing number".

Comment: I thought I had? The "SQL that gets me the schedule" portion of the question. Updated just in case!

Comment: See MyISAM's 2-column `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Do you want to do this as a one-time/on demand update, or are you looking for a stored procedure/automated functionality?